# How to break Horizontal Scroll List vertically?

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart, material-design, user-experience

I have a list view with horizontal scroll. Inside it, there are choice chips that can be selected.
However, all the chips appear on one long horizontal line. I want them to break into another line when reaching the screen limit.

Then, the whole list view can be scrolled, with multiple vertical chip lines.

What I have:

```
ListView(children: <Widget>[
   Container(
   child: ListView(scrollDirection: 
   Axis.horizontal,
   children: <Widget>[ChoiceChipDisplay()]
```

Chip Display:

```
ChoiceChipDisplay() {
    List<Widget> choices = List();
    widget.reportList.forEach((item) {
      choices.add(Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
        child: ChoiceChip(
          label: Text(item),
          labelStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xffededed),
          selectedColor: Color(0xffffc107),
          selected: selectedChoice == item,
          onSelected: (selected) {
            setState(() {
              selectedChoice = item;
              print(selectedChoice)
```

I've tried to Wrap them and set a horizontal direction limit but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [Wrap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Wrap(
            spacing: 4.0,
            children: <Widget>[
              for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++)
                ChoiceChip(
                  label: Text("item $i"),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                  ),
                  backgroundColor: Color(0xffededed),
                  selectedColor: Color(0xffffc107),
                  selected: false,
                  onSelected: (b) {},
                )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]